# Cypress - mocking window property

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a code that uses window.foo.abc as a condition to display something.

I want to test this functionality with cypress and I want to mock this value to be false and true.

How can I do that?

I've tried

```
 before(function() {
      Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
        win.foo.abc = true;
      });
```

and

```
  cy.window().then(win => {
    window.foo.abc = true;
  });
```

with no success.

How can I mock this value?

thanks

Comment: You should edit the 2nd code block - that's also incorrect, see my sample below.

Comment: Also change `Cypress.window()` to `cy.window()`

Answer (score 5):

This code is incorrect,

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
  window.foo.abc = true;
});
```

It should be

```js
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
  win.foo.abc = true;
});
```

You don't have to use it in `before()`, but it should be at the top of the spec.

But I suspect it still won't work after correcting, most likely the app resets `foo` to a new object during loading, i.e during `cy.visit()`

You can use the 2nd block

```js
cy.visit('...')  // visit before changing

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.foo.abc = true;            // correct the syntax here as well
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fody. indeed I pasted it wrong. the thing I tried is with win and it doesn't work as well. 
moving this code after visit also not working. 
I also tried to debug with chrome and i tried to write win.foo.abc = true; and then win.foo.abc; and it showed false. so why the cypress will manage to change it...?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm wondering if there's a "read-only" aspect to the property. Let me see if I can duplicate it.

Comment: So tried with a "writable: false" on property `abc`, but the message in the Cypress log is pretty obvious - so that's not it.

Comment: Did discover that `Cypress.window()` is also illegal syntax, it should be `cy.window()` but that also gives an obvious error message so presume you just mis-typed in the question.

Comment: lol, yes indeed... Thanks a lot for the checking..! highly appreciate. Didn't know about the writable: false thing - good approach. And just because I'm out of ideas - is there maybe a way to add a condition to the code the invoked only in case of Cypress test...? that way, although it's ugly, we can maybe use it in the test instead of mocking...